# AGPM - Unable to deploy a gpo - There is no such object on the server

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

We recently installed AGPM in production but on our first deploy we are having issues.  Some of the files that we deployed would disapear after 15 minutes.

We managed to control the gpo and deploy it once.  We go to redeploy it again and we are greeted with the following screen.

[image]

We get the same message on every attempt to redeploy the gpo.

We also noticed that every time we try to deploy, there's a duplicate folder being created in AD under 
Domain/system/policies/{guid} (In ADSIEdit)

[image]

There will be an extra machine folder every time we try a deploy.

Not sure if this is just a symptom of our replication issues or the cause of it.  The event log on the DC isn't mentioning anything related to this gpo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AGPM server may not be locating the PDCe as GPMC or the Group Policy Object Editor normally does:

See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-ca/archive/blogs/389thoughts/find-out-what-sysvol-on-dfsr-is-doing-part-2

> So, AGPM does not play nice by selecting the PDC as it really should,
>   but just picks a random DC in its own site.

Try either of the options to see which works best:

1. Create a /32 subnet for the AGPM server and put it in the same site as the PDCe - this will force the AGPM server to get its information from the PDCe and not the local DC. This is the preferred option.
   Restart the netlogon service and run NLtest /DSGetDC:*Domain_DNS* to verify that it is locating the PDCe.
2. Configure the group policy setting *User Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Group Policy - Configure Group Policy domain controller selection* (https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#338). Note that this is a user scoped setting.

Comment: We ended up moving the install for APGM onto the same DC as the PDC.